# How to use group by in rows?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

How to group the below data ? as I am looping through the collection and it gives me only 1 row as there is no grouping in place.
I have to group the below records based on Id column and if there are repeating Ids ? I have to populate model with that many rows.

```
id  name    trID    trName
1   a         5     x
2   b         6     y
2   c         7     z
3   d         8     m
3   e         9     n
4   f         10    0


class DataModel
{

  Public int Id{get;set;}
  Public string name{get;set;}
  Public RepeatedIDs RepeatedIDCollection{get;set;} 

}

class RepeatedIDs 
{
  Public int trId{get;set;}
  Public string trname{get;set;}
}

(from DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows
 select new IdModel
 {
     Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ID"]),
     name = Convert.ToString(dr["name"]),

     // need to group the records here and populate below mode with that many rows
     RepeatedIDCollection =  new List<RepeatedIDs>
        {
            new RepeatedIDs()
            {
                trId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["trId"]),
                trname = Convert.ToString(dr["trname"]),
            }
        }
 }).ToList();
```

Comment: You could try this dataTable.Rows.GroupBy(x=>x.Id).Select(g=>new {Id=g.Key}

Answer (score 0):

What you need is:

```
var query = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => r.Field<int>("ID"))
    .Select(grp => new DataModel
    {
        Id = grp.Key,
        name = String.Join(",", grp.Select(t => t.Field<string>("name"))), //Because there could be multiple names
        RepeatedIDCollection = grp.Select(t => new RepeatedIDs
        {
            trId = t.Field<int>("trID"),
            trname = t.Field<string>("trName")
        }).ToList(),
    });
```

What this query is doing:

- Grouping the data based on ID column in `DataTable`
- Later selecting an object of `DataModel`
- The `Id` in `DataModel` is the key from group.
- There will be multiple names in the grouped data
- Later it creates a `List<RepeatedIDCollection>` by getting the `trId` and `trname` from grouped collection.

Make sure you specify the correct types in `Field` method.

Comment: I have one more column of type Datetime, if I use that next to name column, I get an error message saying that "cannot convert sourcetype System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Datetime> to targettype 'System.Datetime'"  and here is my code which is almost similar to what you have suggested, I have only changed the column type CreateDate = grp.Select(t => t.Field<DateTime>("RecordCreatedDatetime"))   - what is it that I am missing ? could you please advise

Comment: @Amit, there are/could be multiple Dates in the grouped records. You need to either select a single/first one or modify your `CreateDate` to accepts collection of dates. If you are going to Select the first one you can do: `CreateDate = grp.First(t => t.Field<DateTime>("RecordCreatedDatetime"))`, *(Remember `First` will throw an exception if no record is found)*

Comment: I am using the First method as from my example of data above, I will have one row that will contain single date value, so first would work. 
However, I am getting one more msg @ line t.Field<DateTime>("RecordCreatedDatetime")  that says cannot convert System.Datetime to bool

Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the values in block are not implicitly convertible.

I have verified the column type and it is of type System.Datetime

Comment: @Amit, are you sure your field named `CreateDate` is of type `DateTime` ?

Comment: yes, I did verified in model at first place to make sure type is correct. this is how it is defined in model  public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

Comment: Is any property missing ? as if I remove date column, all looks good, no error... I am clueless here...

Comment: this is how I made change.... no error ... need to test.....CreateDate = Convert.ToDateTime(grp.First()["RecordCreatedDatetime"]),

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof (int));
            dt.Columns.Add("name", typeof (string));
            dt.Columns.Add("trID", typeof (int));
            dt.Columns.Add("trName", typeof (string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1,"a", 5,"x"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2,"b", 6,"y"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2,"c", 7,"z"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3,"d", 8,"m"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3,"e", 9,"n"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4,"f", 510,"0"});

            var groups = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("id")).ToList();

        }
    }



}
```